# Getting line number for runaway argument

Tags: errors, tex-core

Quite frequently TeX hangs for various errors or gives an off-the-wall error message either without an line number or with a line number hundreds of lines away from the actual error. In many of these cases, xetex gives an appropriate error message with the correct line number. Is there a way to get the same information from TeX, or is xetex the best workaround?

Comment: XeTeX shares the code with TeX in that area, so I don't think you get different diagnostic messages.

Comment: A “runaway” argument can be inherently a hundred lines long; but TeX should display the first token in the argument, too.

Comment: The first token doesn't really help in a large paper where the same text occurs multiple times, while the line number at which the first argument begins would be helpful. I definitely got different results with TeX and xetex with an intervening interval of seconds and no intervening edit, so something is obviously different. My guess would be an uninitialized variable, but that's worth what you paid for it.

Comment: Kind of duplicate : [braces - how to debug runaway argument? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/567978/how-to-debug-runaway-argument)